"If I'd planted seeds in spring" vs. "If I planted seeds in spring"
What is the difference in meaning between

If I'd planted seeds in spring, I would have tomatoes now.

and

If I planted seeds in spring, I would have tomatoes now.


Finding errors is off-topic here. You have to ask a specific question about learning English. What do you think is the difference? Why do you doubt what you think?

The first one expresses a wish that you had planted some tomato seeds earlier this year. If I planted seeds in spring  is a general statement that could refer to any year - it could be followed by I would have tomatoes in the summer.

The second could be an example of the first but spoken by someone who doesn't  use the past perfect much in their speech. Not all native speakers use the past perfect and many of them would not do well on an ESL test that focused on that tense.

@Astralbee Certainly more explanation is needed, but there was no implication that either is in error. To Hey: you can get better answers by telling a bit more. Is there a particular meaning that you want?

OP wants to know the difference between two Conditional Sentences.
I. First sentence = Mixed Conditional (Past → Present)

If I'd planted seeds in spring, I would have tomatoes now.


If + past perfect (e.g., If I'd planted)
Would + present perfect or present simple (e.g., I would have tomatoes now).
The mixed conditional refers to a past event that didn’t happen, affecting the present..

Meaning: The speaker didn’t plant seeds in spring but is imagining how doing so would affect the present (having tomatoes)..

Mixed conditionals.
We can use mixed conditionals when we imagine a past change with a result in the present or a present change with a result in the past.
Here's a sentence imagining how a change in a past situation would have a result in the present.

If I hadn't got the job in Tokyo, I wouldn't be with my current partner.


II. Second Sentence: Second Conditional (Present/Future Hypothetical)

If I planted seeds in spring, I would have tomatoes now.

Meaning: The speaker is imagining planting seeds in spring, but it’s unlikely or impossible (perhaps due to lack of space).
The second conditional imagines an unlikely present or future scenario.
It is used for hypothetical or imaginary situation

*Second conditional".
The second conditional is used to imagine present or future situations that are impossible or unlikely in reality.

If we had a garden, we could have a cat.
If I won a lot of money, I'd buy a big house in the country.
I wouldn't worry if I were you..
.
The structure is usually: if + past simple >> + would + infinitive.



Is the first one incorrect or is it a mixed conditional?

@Hey The first sentence is a mixed conditional sentence. The mixed conditional refers to a past event that didn’t happen, affecting the present.

'had planted' is past perfected in a 3rd conditional ie imagining the outcome of 'having tomatoes', but clearly impossible. On its own 'planted' is a past participle in a clause considering consequences of future events equiv to "If I was to plant..." and is 2nd conditional.
OTOH and given the climate uncertainty, best bet is to purchase at market.
